# Дефис или тире в сочетании "врач - детский хирург"?

Tags: орфография

Быть может, тире, но короткое?

То же касается выражения "медицинская сестра - анестезист"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире - в обоих случаях. Когда соединяются две части, одна из которых состоит более чем из одного слова, дефис заменяется на тире. (Если надо - найду точную формулировку у Розенталя, сейчас лениво).

В Ваших примерах дефис в первом случае вообще невозможен (слова "врач-детский" не существует), а во втором означал бы, что "медицинская" относится не только к "сестра", но и к "анестезист". Кстати, она разве не ***анестезиолог***?

Короткое тире - знак типографский, не пунктуационный, поэтому его постановка правилами орфографии и пунктуации не регулируется.